Ubuntu server reboot not working after symlink change - live usb can not make the fix
I have accidently made a wrong symlink So currently rebooting does not work
This error occurs after I have accidently changed the symlink of glibc as below
sudo ln -sf /opt/glibc-2.38/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

How can I restore and fix it?
[current status]

I am trying to solve this with a live USB mounted and creating a new symlink, but I cannot chroot because of the broken symlink. Is there a solution?

Can I just do the below command directly without chroot?
sudo ln -sf /mnt/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.35.so /mnt/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2


Your question lacks a very important detail. What is the version of Ubuntu you are using?

It is Ubuntu server 20.04

Do you really need to chroot into the broken system? isn't mounting the broken system's root filesystem rw sufficient to allow you to make the correct link?

This appears to have been crossposted here albeit under a different user account
